# how do you take a value stored in a multi dimensional array (Android)?

Tags: android, arrays

I am trying to get a value stored in my Array (the correct  answer) and compare it with the answer the user enters.

This is my Array:

```
String [][] multiArray = {{"4 + 5 = ", "9"},     
        {"20 * 3 - 1 = ","59"},
        {"99 - 9 = ","90"},
        {"50 / 2 + 18 = ","43"},
        {"9 * 8 = ","72"},
        {"4 + 20 - 20 = ","4"},
        {"75 / 5 = ","15"},
        {"99 - 1 * 3 = ","96"},
        {"75 + 25 = ","100"}};
```

And this is the method where it works out if the answer is correct or incorrect. If it is incorrect and the hint option is checked. It should compare the users entered answer and the correct answer in the array. But how would i get the value from the array if the array is randomly generated?

```
public void hash_Clicked(View v){

    // Get the Answer from your EditText
    String answer =  display.getText().toString();
    setAnswer.setText(answer);


    // Using a for loop iterate on the base index
    for(int i = 0; i < multiArray.length ; i++)
    {      
        // if the answer is in position 1 of Array [i] 
        if(answer.equals(multiArray[i][1]))
        {
            // We have found the answer, Congratulate the User 
            displayAnswer.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
            displayAnswer.setText("CORRECT");
            break;

         }else{
             // Tell them how bad they are since they can't solve simple equations!
             displayAnswer.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
             displayAnswer.setText("INCORRECT");

             for (int count = 0; count<5; count++){
                 if(Prefs.getHints(this)){
                     if (answer > multiArray[1]){
                         setHints.setText("greater");
                     }
                 }

             }
         }


    }


}
```

This is the code that generates a random expression:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            Random ranGenerate = new Random ();
            int random = ranGenerate.nextInt(multiArray.length) ;
            // Fetch your random question
            String Rquestion = multiArray[random][0];
            displayExpression.setText(Rquestion);
            displayAnswer.setText("");
            setAnswer.setText("?");

        }
```

This is where i need help:

```
if (answer > multiArray[i][1]){
                     setHints.setText("greater");
                 }
```

It says The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.String, java.lang.String. SO how would i take the value from the array?

Comment: I am not sure i understand you correctly. You already know what the question is. Couldn't you just index the answer with the question, even if the array is random generated?

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I think you're probably not describing your problem accurately.

`public void onClick(View v)` doesn't seem to be "generating" an array as you say. It selects a random question from the existing `multiArray[][]`.

That being said, you could just store the random value generated there as a variable so you always know what question the user is currently answering...

**EDIT:**

After seeing your edit.

You're working with strings, you must convert them to a numeric type (`int`, `float`, `double`, etc.).

```
// (Do some checkings before parsing, as the user may have inputted text...)
if (Integer.parseInt(answer) > Integer.parseInt(multiArray[i][1])){
    setHints.setText("greater");
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

You could store the current question's position in a variable in your `Activity`. Whenever you choose a new random question (in `onClick(View v)`), memorize the position of the selected question in that variable.

Then when you want to validate the user's answer, you know that the answer is in `multiArray[random][1]`. Parse the values for the user's answer and the correct answer from `string` to *int*, etc.

```
class MyActivity extends Activity{

    int random; // store the current question...

    String [][] multiArray = {{"4 + 5 = ", "9"},     
        {"20 * 3 - 1 = ","59"},
        {"99 - 9 = ","90"},
        {"50 / 2 + 18 = ","43"},
        {"9 * 8 = ","72"},
        {"4 + 20 - 20 = ","4"},
        {"75 / 5 = ","15"},
        {"99 - 1 * 3 = ","96"},
        {"75 + 25 = ","100"}}; 

    public void onClick(View v) {
            Random ranGenerate = new Random ();
            random = ranGenerate.nextInt(multiArray.length);
            // Fetch your random question
            String Rquestion = multiArray[random][0];
            displayExpression.setText(Rquestion);
            displayAnswer.setText("");
            setAnswer.setText("?");

    }

    public void hash_Clicked(View v) {

        // 1 - The correct answer for current question is in multiarray[i][1]
        // 2 - Parse the strings to int/double/float
        // 3 - Do your checkings...
        // (careful as i might haven't been initialized)
    }    

}
```

Comment: Yes, sorry that was a typo. the random expressions are fetched

Comment: But isn't `int random = ranGenerate.nextInt(multiArray.length) ;` storing the random value. How would i take only the answer out and not the expression from the random value stored?

Comment: The answer is always in position multiArray[?][1], right? The int random could be stored as a variable in your activity. That way you always know what question is currently selected. The answer would then be on multiArray[random][1].

Comment: But if i compare like you have said in your edit above, It doesn't compare whether the answer in the array is the same as the answer the user entered. Could you clarify what is the value of `Integer.parseInt(multiArray[i][1])`, please. I am getting confused now.

Comment: What I mean is that you could just store the index for the current question's position in a variable in your activity. That way, you always know the current question and the answer will always be in [theCurrentQuestionPosition][1]. See the edit. I'm afraid I can't make it any clearer.

Comment: Don't worry i found out what `Integer.parseInt(multiArray[i][1])` was doing. The only reason it wasn't giving me the correct answer is because i had my condition set to > instead of < . Thank You, for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (answer > multiArray[i][1]){
    setHints.setText("greater");
}
```

You should convert both strings to Integers to compare them.

```
if (Integer.valueOf(answer) > Integer.valueOf(multiArray[i][1])) {
    setHints.setText("greater");
}
```

Or `Integer.parseInt()`